# Entity Framework 6 relacionamento

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Tenho uma classe em que preciso ter 2 relacionamentos diferentes com a mesma tabela.

```js
public class Usuario
{
    public int Naturalidade {set;get;}
    public int CidadeEndereco {set;get; 
}

public class Cidade
{
   public int Id {set;get;}
   public string Nome {set;get;
}
```

Como faço este relacionamento? Pode ser usando Fluente API ou Data Annotation?

Comment: Aqui tem sua resposta https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você trata normalmente, como se fossem entidades separadas.

```
public class Usuario
  {

    public int NaturalidadeId {set;get;}
    public int CidadeEnderecoId {set;get;

     [ForeignKey("NaturalidadeId ")]
     public virtual Cidade Naturalidade{ get; set; }
     [ForeignKey("CidadeEnderecoId ")]
     public virtual Cidade CidadeEndereco{ get; set; }
}

public class Cidade
{

   public int Id {set;get;}
   public string Nome {set;get;

}
```